# Is calling a "noexcept function" through a "function" lvalue undefined?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, function-pointers, undefined-behavior, noexcept

[[expr.call]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call#6):

> Calling a function through an expression whose [function type](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct) is different from the function type of the called function's definition results in undefined behavior.

```
void f() noexcept {}; // function type is "noexcept function"
void (*pf)() = f; // variable type is "pointer to function"; initialized by result of [conv.fctptr]([conv.func](f))
int main()
{
    (*pf)(); // `*pf`: lvalue expression's function type is "function" (without noexcept!)
}
```

Does the above call result in undefined behavior per the cited standardese?

Comment: This is a defect.

Comment: Seems pretty clear that the exception specification is part of what has to match.  http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#8   One suspects that there should not be implicit conversion between incompatible function and pointer-to-function types but the conversion removing `noexcept` is explicitly permitted http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.fctptr#1

Comment: @t.c I don't see it http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html - new defect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++14 had a weaker requirement, from [[expr.call]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr.call#1):

> [...] Calling a function through an expression **whose function type has a language linkage** that is different from the language linkage of the function type of the called function's definition is undefined ([dcl.link]). [...]

However [[expr.reinterpret.cast]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr.reinterpret.cast#6) contained a similar, but stronger requirement:

> A function pointer can be explicitly converted to a function pointer of a different type. The effect of calling a function through a pointer to a function type ([dcl.fct]) **that is not the same as the type** used in the definition of the function is undefined.

[P0012R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0012r1) made exception specifications to be part of the type system, and was [implemented for C++17](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/p0636r0.html)

> The exception specification of a function is now part of the function’s type: `void f() noexcept(true);` and `void f() noexcept(false);` are functions of two distinct types. Function pointers are convertible in the sensible direction. (But the two functions `f` may not form an overload set.) This change strengthens the type system, e.g. by allowing APIs to require non-throwing callbacks.

and moreover added [conv.fctptr]:

> Add a new section after section 4.11 [conv.mem]:
>
> > 4.12 [conv.fctptr] Function pointer conversions
> >
> > A prvalue of type "pointer to noexcept function" can be converted to a prvalue of type
> > "pointer to function". [...]

but included no changes to [[expr.reinterpret.cast]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr.reinterpret.cast#6); arguably an unintentional omission.

[CWG 2215](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2215) highlighted the duplicated information in [expr.call] compared to [expr.reinterpret.cast]/6, flagging the weaker requirement in the former as redundant. [The following `cplusplus / draft` commit](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/411f35a2aa57681f11018a2914efb19bd9920a6b) implemented CWG 2215, and removed the weaker (redundant) requirement, made [expr.reinterpret.cast]/6 into a non-normative note and moved its (stronger) normative requirement to [expr.call]; eventually this stronger requirement was broken out into its own paragraph.

This confusion arguably lead to the unintentional (seemingly conflicting) rules that:

- a prvalue of type “pointer to `noexcept` function” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to function” ([[conv.fctptr]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.fctptr#1)), and
- calling a function through an expression whose function type is different only by its exception specification is undefined behaviour.

Afaict, there are no defect reports covering this issue, and a new one should arguably be submitted.